# How to use variables from downloaded data set in checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a dynamic checkboxGroupInput based on list of columns from downloaded in server

I have tried global variables, updatecheckboxGroupInput and RenderUi

```
        # UI.R 

    sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("fileInPath", 
            label= h4("Import danych"), accept=("text/csv")),
        radioButtons('plott','Plot',c('ggplot2'='ggplot2', 'lattice'='lattice')
            ),
        radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                     inline = TRUE),
        downloadButton('downloadReport',label="Wygeneruj raport"),
        uiOutput("ListOfColumns")

       ),


#Server.R

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {



# 3 wczytywanie danych 
dataIn <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$fileInPath

    if (is.null(inFile)) {
        return(NULL)
    }
    read.table(file=inFile$datapath,sep=";",dec=",",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
output$ListOfColumns <- renderUI({
columns <- colnames(dataIn)
  checkboxGroupInput("Columns", "Choose columns", columns)
})}
```

I expect list of columns from downloaded  file to appeare in checkboxGroupInput.

Comment: You could set up hidden checkboxGroupInput at start, and then update it via shiny::updateCheckboxGroupInput() after finishing reading your file (put update in the end of dataIn).

Comment: What do you mean hidden checkboxGroupInput?

Comment: You need to intialize to update I think, so before anyone input files you can hid input with shinyjs::hide(), and then first time when someone updates you can show it.

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

but I feel like the main bug in your example is on the second last line

`columns <- colnames(dataIn)`

It should be

`columns <- colnames(dataIn())`

### Working Example

I used a sample csv file to test to the file reading and parsing is slightly different from your example.

```
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("fileInPath", "Choose File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
      radioButtons('plott','Plot',c('ggplot2'='ggplot2', 'lattice'='lattice')
      ),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport',label="Wygeneruj raport"),
      uiOutput("ListOfColumns")

    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)



  #Server.R

  server = function(input, output) {

    # 3 wczytywanie danych 
    dataIn <- reactive({
      req(input$fileInPath)
      read.csv(file=input$fileInPath$datapath)
    })

    output$ListOfColumns <- renderUI({
      req(dataIn())
      columns <- colnames(dataIn())

      checkboxGroupInput("Columns", "Choose columns",columns)
    })}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I tested it with the `mtcars` data set which you can save to your computer with

`write.csv(mtcars,file = "~/Desktop/Data.csv",row.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with dynamically rendering UI like you tried before with a few changes in your code.  However make sure you correctly import your data to the server. To check this you can add a `tableOutput` to you mainpanel.
It can be also achieved this by hiding checkboxGroup input at start and show it when your data is loaded  by controlling `if(nrow(dataIn)>0)` then show... I do not have much knowledge about this package.

Try this one and let me know if this solves your problem. give us a sample of your data with `dput()`to try better. 
I edited the code. You can also see head of your data frame now.

## UI.R

```
ui<-fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("fileInPath", 
        label= h4("Import danych"), accept=("text/csv")),
    radioButtons('plott','Plot',c('ggplot2'='ggplot2', 'lattice'='lattice')
        ),
    radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                 inline = TRUE),
    downloadButton('downloadReport',label="Wygeneruj raport"),
    uiOutput("ListOfColumns")

          ),
  mainPanel(
  tableOutput("datacheck")
     )
    )
   )
 #Server.R

 shinyServer(function(input, output) {



 # 3 wczytywanie danych 
  dataIn <- reactive({
  req(input$fileInPath)
  read.csv(input$fileInPath$datapath)
  output$datacheck<-renderTable({ 
  if (is.null(dataIn)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
 head(dataIn())
   })




  columns <- reactive({colnames(dataIn())
                                           })
  output$ListOfColumns <- renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput("Columns", "Choose columns", choices=columns())
  })     
  }
```